# Font not loading - CORS says header contains no Access Control but there is

Tags: .htaccess, cors, cross-domain

The problem: I am using html generated from one site that is being pushed to another site (different domains). All is working well except the font (used mainly for icons) is not showing up. I am receiving a CORS error as described further below.

I have added the following code to my .htaccess file on the site where the fonts are stored that allows fonts to be access across any domain:

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

I checked the header using cUrl:

```
curl -I https://mywebsite.com/fonts/flatpack.woff?tzy7cr
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 18:33:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 142020
Connection: keep-alive
X-Accel-Version: 0.01
Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 17:49:02 GMT
ETag: "1a474c-22ac4-552a4378235b7"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The Access Origin response tells me that the font should be readable but I'm still getting this error from the requesting website:

> Access to Font at https://mywebsite/fonts/flatpack.woff?tzy7cr' from
>   origin 'http://anotherwebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://anotherwebsite.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Thoughts or suggestions???

Edit: Here is a [live link](http://response.newmanu.edu/test123) to a test page that fails to load the icon fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Almost got it right:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
```

You need to `add` the header not `set`. I'd also add the method to be sure.

Comment: No dice... Still getting the error: `Access to Font at 'https://intranet.newmanu.edu/landing/pages/danatest/fonts/flatpack.woff?tzy7cr' from origin 'http://response.newmanu.edu' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://response.newmanu.edu' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: ...even though the response in the header shows this: `curl -I https://intranet.newmanu.edu/landing/fonts/flatpack.woff?tzy7cr
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 29 Jun 2017 14:43:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 142020
Connection: keep-alive
X-Accel-Version: 0.01
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 22:03:28 GMT
ETag: "1a3c9c-22ac4-5526b6be0b722"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET`

Comment: Is the headers mod enabled? (a2enmod headers) Was the server restarted (or at least reloaded) after the change?

Answer (score 0):

Premium font purchased by some other website can be abused another site. That is the reason of complication at browser level coding. Image will not suffer such issue. Font related CORS is complicated by types of fonts, browsers and bugs. Unless you are using paid origin pull CDN or known font provider (free or paid), it is practical to serve font from own server for the sake of making sure that font loads on all browsers, all devices. It is worthy to read :

1. [official W3 doc about CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/),
2. [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS),
3. [MaxCDN's guide](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/how-to-use-cdn-with-webfonts/),
4. [W3's CSS font doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/),
5. [this old bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604421)
6. [this pull request](https://github.com/mozilla/kitsune/pull/2753/files)

There are three options from the above resources for giving you a correct answer. You need to test from webpagetest dot org from different user agents & devices and try to watch the video of screenshot.

One :

```
SetEnvIf Origin "https?://(.*\.(mozilla|allizom)\.(com|org|net))" CORS=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS}e env=CORS

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|woff|eot)$">
    Header append vary "Origin"
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
```

Two (Single domain, HTTPS) :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
        SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?anotherwebsite\.com$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</FilesMatch>
```

Three (Multiple domains) :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(anotherwebsite.com|cdn.anotherwebsite.com|blahblah.anotherwebsite.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Also make sure that proper MIME types are present :

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
AddType application/font-woff            .woff
AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2
```

Make sure to run Apache configtest before restarting. You may need to activate some module.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to take credit for the answer, but this worked for me, thanks to this guy:

https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

**Add below lines to .htaccess file and put it inside your (font) folder:**

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```